# Gateway as oauth client sometimes redirect several times before invoke the targer service

Tags: spring-security, oauth-2.0, gateway

[the picture of detail information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xm5pR.png)
I am trying to build a microservice architecture, and the gateway is a oauth client and I build my own oauth server, when i try to acess some api interface, sometime it redirect two more times then give me the correct response, why this happened, its so wired and during the whole process i dont' need fill usename and password. it all happend automatically, but this is hard for fornt end developer

I have already configed the referesh code config.

```
@Bean
@Primary
public ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedClientManager(
ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository,
ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository authorizedClientRepository) {

        // @formatter:off
        ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientProvider authorizedClientProvider =
                ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientProviderBuilder.builder()
                        .authorizationCode()
                        .refreshToken()
                        .clientCredentials()
                        .build();
        // @formatter:on
        DefaultReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedClientManager = new DefaultReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager(
                clientRegistrationRepository, authorizedClientRepository);
        authorizedClientManager.setAuthorizedClientProvider(authorizedClientProvider);
    
        return authorizedClientManager;
    }
```

but this doesn't work